# Subscription synchronization data will lose data

Tags: database, cnosdb

I used cnosdb to subscribe between multiple clusters, but after multiple executions, I found that the target cluster was always missing some data.My execution steps are as follows：

1. ceate subscription

   ```
   create subscription sub001 on  benchmark DESTINATIONS any "127.0.0.1:8913" "127.0.0.1:8923" ;
   ```

   2. import data to source cluster;

```
       cat Downloads/cnosdb-2023-01-03-16-17-1000r-data|./bin/load_cnosdb --urls 'http://localhost:8902' --batch-size 10
data source：
```

3.  check the data row;

```
source:
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 1000            |
+-----------------+
Query took 32.788 seconds.
DESTINATIONS 1
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 490             |
+-----------------+
Query took 3.129 seconds.
DESTINATIONS 2
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 500             |
+-----------------+
Query took 3.126 seconds.
```

I then tested it several times and the results are as follows:

100 rows:

```
cat Downloads/cnosdb-2023-01-03-16-17-100r-data|./bin/load_cnosdb --urls 'http://localhost:8902' --batch-size 10
data source：
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 100             |
+-----------------+
Query took 6.641 seconds.
DESTINATIONS 1
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 40              |
+-----------------+
Query took 0.242 seconds.
DESTINATIONS 2
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 50              |
+-----------------+
Query took 0.482 seconds.
```

50rows

```
cat Downloads/cnosdb-2023-01-03-16-17-50r-data|./bin/load_cnosdb --urls 'http://localhost:8902' --batch-size 10
data source
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 50              |
+-----------------+
Query took 3.819 seconds.
DESTINATIONS 1
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 25              |
+-----------------+
Query took 0.208 seconds.
DESTINATIONS 2
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from readings;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 24              |
+-----------------+
Query took 0.285 seconds.
```

Why is some data here lost every time? Has anyone else encountered this?